# apache mod_crypto CryptoKey issues

Tags: apache, openssl

I've been experimenting with the new mod_crypo module in the development version of Apache 2.5 here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_crypto.html

What I'm trying to do is simply serve an encrypted file at rest that will be run through the output filter and decrypted and sent to the client.

The issue I'm having is that that I'm error from mod_crypto that my key is not found.

Here is my setup:

1. encrypted a file to serve from a data/ directory using:

```
[root@fedora data]# cat enc.html | openssl enc -aes128 -nosalt -pbkdf2 -k secret -P -out enc.html
key=FEC291A27F4FB8C70A4013DF167B7DCA
iv =B7FC9929066E7415515F4A5006B3C43D
[root@fedora data]#
```

2. In my apache config I set the CryptoDriver, output filter, same cipher aes128, and CryptoKey and CryptoIV to the hex values output from openssl in step 1

```
CryptoDriver openssl

<Directory "${DOCROOT}/data">
    SetOutputFilter DECRYPT
    CryptoCipher aes128
    
    CryptoKey hex:FEC291A27F4FB8C70A4013DF167B7DCA
    CryptoIV hex:B7FC9929066E7415515F4A5006B3C43D

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. Restart apache `bin/apachectl restart`
4. Try to load the encrypted file at: `http://localhost/data/enc.html`
5. This results in a 500 internal server error, and in the logs I see:

```
Mon Feb 27 15:33:23.732349 2023] [crypto:error] [pid 20554:tid 140718246962752] [client ::1:59314] AH03414: no key specified for this URL
```

I also tried moving the key to a file then I get a different error saying that the key should be 16 length but was 32.

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong here? Again my main goal is to automatically decrypt encrypted files at rest using the mod_crypto DECRYPT output filter.

FYI, I compiled both apache and apr with the enable crypto flags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary work around that works in Apache 2.4, but it might not be the most efficient at scale, but it works to decrypt encrypted files at rest which is exactly what I wanted:

```
  ExtFilterDefine decrypt mode=output \
    cmd="/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -d \
    -pass pass:${ACCESS_KEY}"
    
  <LocationMatch "/encrypted/">
      # decrypt content at request time
      SetOutputFilter decrypt
  </LocationMatch>
```